# Syntacts error in mysql query

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

Someone gave me this query to delete `community` from a database on my server using phpMyAdmin, it worked when he use it so I asked him to send it to me, but I get a error

MySQL said:

```
Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"SELECT * FROM `connections` WHERE 1" :
delete from connections where communit' at line 1
```

I did a search on the error but could not figure it out.

```
"SELECT * FROM `connections` WHERE 1" :
delete from connections where community="XYZ"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are receiving as you've shown it is because this line is incorrect:

```
SELECT * FROM `connections` WHERE 1"
```

First because it's ending in an unnecessary double quotation mark. MySQL does not use double quotes but single quotes, and even still the other single quote is not there to match it.

The single quotes are also a problem for `community="XYZ"`, this should read: `community = 'XYZ'`

Secondly, you don't have a condition for your where statement, you must be missing something like:

```
WHERE columnName = 1;
```

If you were trying to select everything from connections, you can just remove that where clause all together.

**EDIT**

In addition, MySQL queries are separated by a semi-colon, not a colon, so MySQL will not realize you are trying two different queries.

Comment: Thank you as you called out there were two problems the `:` and the `"`.  I can't imagine why someone down grated your answer?

Comment: @Tim well, you can't win them all. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

You should separate your queries with `;` and not `:`

Comment: Thank you that was one of the problems